# Thank you for **sharing us** the screenshot

Tags: word-usage

Is the following sentence correct?

> Thank you for **sharing us** the screenshot.

Nobody can share us, isn't this sentence incorrect?

Ideally, it should be "**Thank you for sharing the screenshot with us.**"

Answer (score 2):

"Share" is usually used in the form:

> Thank you for sharing the screenshot with us.

The form you quote is non-standard, but understandable. It's "wrong" but not very wrong.